# How to override txt file on secondary storage( sdcard/Downloads) on Android 11 or later version

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I want to override a txt file that is present in secord storage sdcard/Downloads folder. Can any one help me for a lead?

I refered the Storage Scope documents but they have very few information for non-media file handling cases.
Would be appreciate if someone guide me.

Comment: Where is that file located? On a removable micro sd card? Please give full path. We do not understand what you consider to be secondary storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override a text file in the external storage directory (e.g., sdcard/Downloads), you can follow these steps in your Android app:

1. Add the necessary permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml file to access external storage:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

2. Check for runtime permissions if your app targets Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher. You'll need to request permission from the user at runtime.

Here's an example of how to check and request permissions:

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted, request it
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
}
```

3. Once you have the necessary permissions, you can use standard Java I/O operations to override the text file in the external storage directory. Here's an example of how to do it:

```java
try {
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File(directory, "your_text_file.txt");
    
    // Check if the file exists before overriding it
    if (file.exists()) {
        // Write your new content to the file (e.g., using FileWriter)
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.write("Your new file content here");
        writer.close();
        
        // You've successfully overridden the file
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the file doesn't exist
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle exceptions, e.g., file not found or permission denied
}
```

Make sure to replace `"your_text_file.txt"` and `"Your new file content here"` with your actual file name and content.

4. Handle exceptions, as shown in the code example, to deal with possible errors like file not found or permission denied.

Keep in mind that handling external storage requires runtime permissions for newer Android versions, and you should handle these permissions accordingly to ensure the security of user data.

Comment: All your code will not work if the file is not created by the app.

Comment: All your permission code never makes any sense on Android 13+ devices.

Comment: @Hezy Ziv Thanks for sharing the approach. I tested it with my app it works perfectly when my application creates this file but when I try to uninstall the APK and install it again, it is not working in this case.

Comment: @blackapps, I agree with your comment. The same I observed, it is not working when it is not created by my app. Do have any suggestions, on how to handle the case when file is not created by my app, but my app can override the same file?

Comment: You have two options. Let the user select the file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. Or implement 'createDeleteIntent' to let the user confirm the delete.